# Riemann Surfaces Question (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface, and denote by $m_X$ the following field:
$ m_X := \{ f:X \to \mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C} : f- \text{meromorphic} \} - \{\infty \} $

What is the natural injection of the field of rational functions $\mathbb{C}(z)$ into $m_X$ ?

p.s- $\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}$ denotes the Riemann sphere.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: If you have a distinguished function $f_0\in m_X$, then the map $g\mapsto g\circ f_0$ from $\mathbb C(z)$ to $m_X$ appears to be natural enough. Otherwise I don't know what *the* natural injection would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me say that emphatically:

**There is no canonical injection of $\mathbb C(z)$ into $\mathcal M(X)$**

To give  an embedding $\mathbb C(z) \hookrightarrow\mathcal M(X)$  exactly amounts  to  choosing  a non-constant morphism $m:X\to \mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$.
If such a choice is made, the deduced field embedding  $\mathbb C(z) \hookrightarrow\mathcal M(X)$ will send $z\mapsto m$, where $m$ is now seen as a meromorphic function on $X$ .

Answer (score 0):

There is no natural map. $m_X$ is a field and $\mathbb C \subset m_X$ is a field extension. Obviously every $f \in m_X$ that is transcendental over $\mathbb C$ defines such an injection.

The really hard part is to show that there exists a non-constant meromorphic function at all!